# how to derive a joint pdf

Tags: probability-distributions, self-learning

I have searched for this question, however,
they only give the definition of joint pdf
 $\iint f(x,y)dxdy =1$
and examples like:
$f(x,y)=x+cy^2, 0\le x\le 1, 0\le y\le 1$
find $c$.

But not for how to derive $f(x,y)$ from 
$f(x)$ and $f(y)$.

I want to know, for example, how to derive a joint pdf $f(x,y)$ of $2$ random variables $X, Y$ from a gamma distribution or from any $2$ distributions?

Hope I can have a calculation example for this,
and a website reference for explaining how this can be done would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to find the joint density $f(x,y)$ from $f_X$ and $f_Y$ in general. When $X$ and $Y$ are independent $f(x,y)=f_X(x)f_Y(y)$.

Comment: Oh, so basically, is the concept of joint PDF is 
$P(X \bigcap Y)= P(X) P(Y|X)$?
And because $X$,$Y$ are independent, so $P(X \bigcap Y)= P(X) P(Y)$ ?